# How do I handle collections in a ViewModel?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nhibernate, mapping, viewmodel, parent-child

I think I've almost got this all figured out.  This question is the context of a .NET MVC application.

**My entity:**   (I'll be switching to *Fluent nHibernate* soon)

```
[Serializable]
[Class(Schema = "dbo", Table = "LiveMedia")]
[Cache(1, Usage = CacheUsage.ReadWrite)]
public class Media : NhBase<Media>
{
    [Id(Name = "Id", Column = "ID"), Generator(1, Class = "native")]
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }

    [Property(Column = "TypeID")]
    public virtual MediaType MediaType { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public virtual DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public virtual DateTime UpdatedAt { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public virtual string EmbedUrl { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public virtual string ThumbnailUrl { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public virtual string S3Filename { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore, Set(0, Table = "LiveCollectionMedia", Schema = "dbo", Cascade = CascadeStyle.AllDeleteOrphan, Lazy = true, Inverse = true), Key(1, Column = "MediaID"), OneToMany(2, Class = "BanffCentre.Business.Data.Live.MediaCollection, BanffCentre")]
    public virtual ISet<MediaCollection> Collections { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore, Set(0, Table = "LiveMediaCategory", Schema = "dbo", Cascade = CascadeStyle.SaveUpdate, Lazy = true), Key(1, Column = "MediaID"), ManyToMany(2, Class = "BanffCentre.Business.Data.Live.Tag, BanffCentre", Column = "CategoryID")]
    public virtual ISet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    public Media()
    {
        Collections = new HashedSet<MediaCollection>();
        Tags = new HashedSet<Tag>();
    }
}
```

**My ViewModel:**

```
public class MediaAudioViewModel
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }
    public MediaType MediaType { get; set; }
    public string ThumbnailUrl { get; set; }
    public IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
    public string S3Filename { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase AudioFile { get; set; }
}
```

**The question:**

I know I shouldn't have a collection of "Tag" entities in my ViewModel:

```
public IList<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
```

So am I suppose to map a **TagViewModel** to this instead?  Like this?

```
public IList<TagViewModel> Tags { get; set; }
```

And if this is a *many-to-many* relationship am I suppose to map a **MediaViewModel** from the **TagViewModel** when I start creating views for the tags?

I imagine so... I just feel like this abstraction stuff gets a little nutty.  Just hoping for a quick confirmation!

Thanks.

**EDIT**

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377524/asp-net-mvc-view-model-best-practices?rq=1) seems to answer my question.  I just found it.  I'd still be interested in any other thoughts.

Answer (score 1):

After doing some more reading I've decide that my view models *should* contain collections of other ViewModels.  Using *AutoMapper* I can usually have this done for me.

```
Mapper.CreateMap<MediaDto, MediaVideoViewModel>();
Mapper.CreateMap<TagDto, TagViewModel>();
var videoModel = Mapper.Map<MediaDto, MediaVideoViewModel>(mediaDto);
```